# Make a copy of object with same address in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nscopying

```
var empObj : EmployeeModel!
var tempObj : EmployeeModel!

tempObj = empObj.copy() as! EmployeeModel
```

whenevr I am copy the `empObj` to `tempObj` it's memory address is changed.I want to prevent this any idea?

Comment: This is obvious  How can two object needs memory  can be at same address ?

Comment: if `EmployeeModel` is class then just do  `tempObj = empObj` now both object will point the same address but change in one object will reflect to other as well because of pass by ref

Answer (score 0):

when you copy its actually making a new reference. instead of copying just assign the value . then both will share the same reference

```
var empObj : EmployeeModel!
var tempObj = empObj
```

Comment: ok but I don't want to reflect any changes on tempobj when I will change empobj.

Comment: if you want to keep temp object  separate from empobj  then you must give it separate memory address.

Comment: In above case when you change the empObj the tempObj will change.

Answer (score 0):

When you want the same address for different values

USE =

for eg.

var ogArray : NSMutableArray()
var tempArray = ogArray

Comment: ok but I don't want to reflect any changes on tempobj when I will change empobj.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using objects two variables can point at the same object so that changing one changes them both, whereas if you tried that with structs you'd find that Swift creates a full copy so that changing the copy does not affect the original. 
If you want to modify copies of a class object so that modifying one object doesn't have an effect on anything else, you can use NSCopying.

- Make your class conform to NSCopying. This isn't strictly required
- Implement the method copy(with:), where the actual copying happens.
- Call copy() on your object.

Example Code for NSCopying

```
 class Person: NSObject, NSCopying {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var age: Int

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age
    }

    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, age: age)
        return copy
    }
}
```

Check the output of this code in Playground

```
let paul = Person(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Hudson", age: 36)
let sophie = paul.copy() as! Person

sophie.firstName = "Sophie"
sophie.age = 6

print("\(paul.firstName) \(paul.lastName) is \(paul.age)")
print("\(sophie.firstName) \(sophie.lastName) is \(sophie.age)")
```

[Reference](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy)